# How was the prebuilt objects in java created?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how they created all of the methods in java, because w/o these objects we wouldn't be able to do much. If there is any website you could link me, it would be much appreciated. & sorry if i am off topic.

Comment: I don't know if you're off topic or not as I'm still trying to figure out just what your question is. Please clarify your question if at all possible.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how the JVM loads classes?

Comment: the objects ( every objects like String, Integer) that are prebuild in java, i am trying to understand how java created them,.

Comment: @pur3extrme: with code, the same as when we create objects. You are welcome to look at the Java source code any time you'd like to see it for yourself. Or if you're talking about the code behind the JVM,... again, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not sure that you're sure even.

Comment: The objects you speak of are part of the standard Java libraries and are included with Java. They're built just like how you build an object (which you can also turn into a JAR file to be a library as well).

Comment: It's like... you need a hammer to make a hammer... how did we make the first hammer, man?!

Comment: @roippi No it isn't. There are no 'prebuilt objects' in Java. There are just classes that get written and compiled same way as any others including yours and mine. There is a tiny amount of collusion between a couple of JDK classes and the compiler, but that's not what the OP appears to be asking about.

Answer (score 2):

> http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/

Here you can see the source code for all the standard library. For example, the String class:

> http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java/?v=source

I think the entire source for the standard lib also comes with the JDK, in some folder somewhere, but I don't remember.

Of course the standard library is not all that makes java, because you also have the JVM. But since you're talking about objects, I guess that's what you want.